# Sublime Text content assis Java

Tags: java, sublimetext2

is there someone that use Sublime Text to write in Java? I do not want use Eclipse anymore but I can not give up a content assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell in Sublime Text only kind of assistance is finishing of words if they already occurred in a document. It's a minimalist tool - powerful in I-am-doing-it-faster not do-things-instead-of-me.

If you want to have content assist there are some others IDEs, namely Netbeans, IntelliJ.

If you want to continue using Sublime Text you need to learn living without that kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

Sublime Text is more for scripting but a nice plugin exists for java : [**Javatar**](https://github.com/spywhere/Javatar) ("*Java Development Plugin for Sublime Text 3*").

List of features:

- Package, Subpackage creation
- Class (also Abstract), Interface, Enumerator snippets with package/class auto-complete
- Project Compile
- Package path in status bar
- Organize Imports
- Rename/Move packages/classes
- JAR file export (included executable)
- Dynamic method call auto-complete

For example, you can create packages:

[image]

---

Don't hesitate to search others plugins here :
https://sublime.wbond.net/search/java